# adding/removing/searching thousands of data

Tags: interaction-design, pagination, windows-os

I have 2 tables : a contract table and a part table.
every contract has thousands of parts.

The user can select a contract and I display the thousands of related parts to the user using paging.

- There needs to be a way to add/remove parts to a selected contract.
- The user also needs a way to check wether the part being added already is existent on the    contract.

Do you know any good way of coming up with this kind of user interface ? What I came up with really sucks.

Comment: You may find the solutions in this question helpful: [Best way to select a subset of items in a long list?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1944/best-way-to-select-a-subset-of-items-in-a-long-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were lacking in detail a little bit but I think I got the idea. I would recommend having the table with the contracts in, and when one is selected the user is presented with the associated parts with that contract and another table with parts they can add to the contract.

You can use a pick list style to add / remove parts to the contract. This will stop users adding products the contract already has. for the selection of products I'd make the whole row clickable to select it or have a checkbox. It would be a bonus if each table was searchable / had pagination.

[image: tables with pick list]

Answer (score 1):

have a contract page where you let search/filter parts of contracts and check/uncheck to include/exclude.
you can have a parts page not related to contracts.
Please go to magento demo and look catalog, manage products, related products to see an example of this pattern.