# Textarea inside of a table. Avoid?

Tags: tables, data-tables

We need an input in a table cell. Table is used for representation of the data. Table can be sorted, it has a border 1px. Depends on the business rule input will be either validated, accepted or disabled.

To my extent I come up with the solution of a textarea in the table. However this approach looks very backward to me, and I think there are other ways to design and structure the solution.

Let me know your thoughts with all pros and cons of each solution. And what impact and level of difficulty of the development process.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a table for styling or why is the textarea there ?

Comment: Table is used for representation of the data. Table can be sorted, it has a border 1px.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot,it would be easier to visualize

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but I can't provide. It's a policy.

I will upload Balsamiq mockups

Comment: Thats fine but you could create a quick mockup using the balsamiq toolbar available hiding critical information. What I dont get is the text in the table editable or are you allowing the user to enter text inside a table field providing a text box field

Comment: Looking at the balsamiq mockup, will you be also be displaying graphs and calender events in the textbox ? Or will it be just text

Comment: Good question: we might want to display some extra graphical data over there, such as Graphs, nothing else. But predominantly we want to display items (elements) in a list format with a small image

Answer (score 3):

It feels like you are mixing apples with bananas here, or in UX terms - the view with actions.

From a software design point of view, there should be a use-case of 'user edits X'. Users also benefit from the knowledge they are now editing something.

It seems that you are dealing with a very simple scenario here, as you did not mention commit/cancel options; but you did mention validation which could yield a message somewhere. Point being is that editing is more than just entering text, and related controls and messages need their own space, which will become an issue if these always exist next to a text area. Although your system may not need it right now, your suggested implementation will be hard to extend if new requirements arise.

Probably the best example against your idea is a spreadsheet - despite being an array of editable cells, only one cell is editable at a time and only upon explicit user action.

One can also easily predict issues with your solution - what if a user enters text in one text area then scrolls that area out of view? Any key strokes will alter data that is out-of-view.

My recommendation would be to keep the table representing the data, but allow an editor upon click / double click (the former could work if no selection is needed).

Depending on the editor complexity and validation/error feedback, you can choose between:

- In place editor (easy, clean and quick, [like in this demo](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/cell-editing.html))
- A dialog (ugly old school, [see this discussion](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23738/what-is-the-best-model-for-editing-and-viewing-data-that-is-summarized-in-a-tabl/24592#24592)).
- A sliding/side dialog ([like in this demo](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/form/form-grid.html)).